# Jquery Dialog box not closing after back button click in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have a jquery dialog box which opens on click of a link . In IE8 it is not closing when browser back button is clicked . It works fine in IE11 . I have given my code snippet below .

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#editUserDetails').dialog({ closeOnEscape: true, title: "Edit User Details", modal: true });
    $('#editUserDetails').dialog('close'); 

    $('#editProfile').click(function () {
        $('#editUserDetails').dialog('open');
        $("#submitEditUser").focus();
    });
});
```

I have tried my possibilities but could not find the answer and I am new to scripting languages. Please help me solve this issue .